Existence of utility use distribution dataset?
I'm not sure if this is the right board to ask this. I'm curious if anyone has stumbled upon a dataset or study of terminal input distributions. Separation of data by fields such as general tasks or experience would be useful but not required.
I've found a few related datasets, though not precisely what I want.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352340921006806 is more cybersecurity focused with a mixture of bash and msfconsole in the user sessions.
https://github.com/magnumresearchgroup/bash_gen is a tool for generating bash commands. It is more for creating an exhaustive set than one detailing use.
NL2BASH and NL2CMD provide command sets with natural language explanations as labels, though those sets have distributions leaning toward find and are, I believe, synthetically generated. I'm looking for real user command distributions.
https://github.com/TellinaTool/nl2bash
Fu, Quchen, et al. "NL2CMD: An Updated Workflow for Natural Language to Bash Commands Translation." arXiv preprint arXiv:2302.07845 (2023).

Any experience anyone has is appreciated. I understand what I'm looking for may not exist, but I wanted to see if anyone else is looking for something similar and make sure I didn't miss anything. Thank you!

What's a "bash utility"? Do you mean shell builtins like cd, help, time, set etc? Why only those? If you also want to look at non-bash tools like ls or cut or grep etc., then I wouldn't expect time to be relevant, it depends more on what kind of tasks people happen to do in the field they're working in.

Apologies for the incorrect terminology. By utility, I mean a shell built-in, non-bash tool and combinations thereof with logical ops, pipes, and redirects. Separation by time is secondary. The purpose of such data is to guide user emulation for synthetic session generation to model the effect of user history on future inputs.

Please [edit] and clarify. The details are important for this sort of thing, but I think you are making a big mistaken assumption here: that there is a "typical" user. I suspect you will instead find there are many different classes of users, with typical examples of each, and each class will have a very different usage pattern. Think Desktop users vs sys admins vs programmers vs scientists etc.

Thank you for the insight. I've edited the question. Separation by class of user in such a way would be helpful. An empirical look into these usage patterns is what I'm looking for to guide the emulation of such classes. You're correct in assuming a singular user behavior profile would be false.
